# How can I generate an access token in my web app to use with Exchange Online Powershell Module?

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, office365, passport.js

I have a user logging into my web app which is already authenticating them for the Office 365 Graph API. I also need to act on behalf of the user to do a couple of things that can only be done via the Exchange Online Powershell. So, I want to pass an access token (generated with passport.js or Go's oauth2) to the script to do those things.

I have used [this helpful post](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1771/hacking-your-way-around-modern-authentication-and-the-powershell-modules-for-office-365) to get almost the whole way there. It shows how to pass credentials to an Exchange online session. But I can't figure out how to get an access token without a client secret. I have the client/app ID and the resource ID  (using the method shown in the linked post) but unless I'm mistaken, I also need a client secret. What am I missing?

(Sorry, I'm a newb in all these areas. Let me know if more info is needed.)

Answer (score 0):

By your definition, you are trying to access a users' mailbox in O365.

Simple answer (this is not a PoSH issue / limitation):
Access / Refresh Tokens are user specific, just like their passwords in ADDS/AAD.

You can't without first being assigned to the O365 Application Impersonation (which auto grants the OnBehalfOfStuff) role for the user(s) or delegation.

Think about it for a second from a risk management perspective. If any AppDev can grab all the users IDAM tokens without the user / admin consent, that is just a non-starter industry-wide.

> Configure impersonation Impersonation enables a caller, such as a
>   service application, to impersonate a user account. The caller can
>   perform operations by using the permissions that are associated with
>   the impersonated account instead of the permissions associated with
>   the caller's account.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-configure-impersonation

This requires you O365/AAD Global Admin to do this for your account / your apps account / service account in advance. Most security folks really balk about just randomly giving this right out, for obvious reasons. Yet, Exchange Application Impersonation can be scoped.

From the link...

> Configuring the ApplicationImpersonation role
>
> When you or your Exchanger server administrator assigns the
>   ApplicationImpersonation role, use the following parameters of the
>   New-ManagementRoleAssignment cmdlet:
>
> •Name – The friendly name of the role assignment. Each time that you
>   assign a role, an entry is made in the RBAC roles list. You can verify
>   role assignments by using the Get-ManagementRoleAssignment cmdlet.
>
> •Role – The RBAC role to assign. When you set up impersonation, you
>   assign the ApplicationImpersonation role.
>
> •User – The service account.
>
> • ***CustomRecipientScope – The scope of users that the service account
>   can impersonate.*** The service account will only be allowed to
>   impersonate other users within the specified scope. If no scope is
>   specified, the service account is granted the ApplicationImpersonation
>   role over all users in an organization. You can create custom
>   management scopes by using the New-ManagementScope cmdlet.